# AWS WAF Captcha token included rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-waf

I have a headless JS application that makes calls to API. I want to secure API calls with captcha checks in case of DDoS attack targeted to API endpoints.

Is there any way to implement AWS JavaScript CAPTCHA on frontend application (by `AwsWafCaptcha.renderCaptcha()`), retrieve `wafToken` after successful solving the captcha send the API call do secured endpoint with `wafToken` included?

Is there any AWS WAF rule configuration that checks if the token is included into the API call (in header/cookie/whatever) and checks for its validity - if valid the request is passed throught, if not some error is returned?